# I am trying to implement per pixel collision into my program but its not working

Tags: c#, monogame

Currently, when you run my code, a square sprite draws whenever and wherever you click the mouse. They fall with gravity. There is also a static black square in the screen to test for collisions, a red square also appears to show that the collision returned true just for the meantime to test the code. However, it totally doesn't work and the red square appears at the wrong time.

```
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
    public Vector2 Origin;
    public float Rotation;

    Texture2D staticSprite; //static sprite used to check collision with moving particle("white circle")

    //white circle gets generated and added to particle list whenever mouse is clicked
    List<Particle> particleList = new List<Particle>();

    public bool mReleased = true; //mouse button released
    public Vector2 clickedMousePos = Vector2.Zero; //default mouse click position
    bool collision = false; // no collision by default

    Rectangle tTextureRectangle = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100);// rectangle placed for 
    Rectangle particleRect;

    //public int particleIndex = 0; **code adding later**

    MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState();

    //PerPixelCollision
    Color[] stiffSpriteData;
    Color[] tTextureData;      

    // intersect method takes two rectangles and color data to check for collision
    static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA, Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
    {
        // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
        int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

        // Check every point within the intersection bounds
        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                // Get the color of both pixels at this point
                Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) +
                            (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) +
                            (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

                // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
                if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                {
                    // then an intersection has been found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // No intersection found
        return false;
    }

    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
        _graphics.ApplyChanges();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        staticSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("whiteCircle");

        //PerPixelCollision
        stiffSpriteData = new Color[staticSprite.Width * staticSprite.Height];
        staticSprite.GetData<Color>(stiffSpriteData);

        

    }



    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        collision = false;      

        mState = Mouse.GetState();

        clickedMousePos = new Vector2 (mState.Position.X, mState.Position.Y); // updated mouse position when clicked

        //draws a particle ("white circle") with garvity and adds to particleList
        if (mState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && mReleased == true)
        {
            particleList.Add(new Particle(Content.Load<Texture2D>("whiteCircle"), new Vector2(0,1), new Vector2(clickedMousePos.X, clickedMousePos.Y), 1f));

            var listSize = particleList.Count - 1;

            //PerPixelCollision
            tTextureData = new Color[particleList[listSize].texture.Width * particleList[listSize].texture.Height];
            particleList[listSize].texture.GetData<Color>(tTextureData);

            //Rectangle generates for first moving particle in list for now
            particleRect = new Rectangle((int)particleList[listSize].Position.X, (int)particleList[listSize].Position.Y, particleList[0].texture.Width, particleList[0].texture.Height);

            mReleased = false; 
        }

        if (mState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            mReleased = true;
        }

        foreach (Particle particle in particleList)
        {
            particle.Update(gameTime);
        }

        // Check collision with person
        if (IntersectPixels(tTextureRectangle, tTextureData, particleRect, stiffSpriteData))
        {
            collision = true;
        }
        


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();

        _spriteBatch.Draw(staticSprite, new Vector2(200, 200), null, Color.Black, Rotation, Origin, 0.1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        foreach (Particle particle in particleList)
        {
             particle.Draw(_spriteBatch);     
        }         

        // this is to test wether a collision was actually detected
        if (collision == true)
        {
            _spriteBatch.Draw(staticSprite, new Vector2(500, 500), null, Color.Red, Rotation, Origin, 0.1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }

        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: What type is `Particle`? Are you using some 3rd party library or is it your own implementation?

Comment: Julian, Welcome to SO. By your coding patterns, it looks like you are either are proficient in JavaScript, or have attempted to adapt existing code to C#.

Comment: Please research "C# Value types and reference types"

Comment: I suggest you try code review. Since your problems are many.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your problem(among too many others) is the `particleRect` variable should not exist in `Game1`, but needs to reference each particle instance (it needs to be referenced from a `foreach` loop of each particle).

I have annotated your code with `//...` comments.

The new Game1.cs:

```
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;


    // ...Objection; it is poor form to treat Game1 as a game object, as it makes, among many other things, menus near impossible.

    // ... The only variables that should be defined here are those pertinent to the entire game (names, difficulty level, score, lives, avatar, level, hasWon, counters for timed events(I would segment per level, but still appropriate here), draw offsets, matrix transforms, aspect ratios ...)
    public Vector2 Origin;
    public float Rotation;
    // ... Nothing in Game1 should have the above properties, but so be it for the minimal example.

    Texture2D staticSprite; //static sprite used to check collision with moving particle("white circle") 
    // ... same objection as above


    //white circle gets generated and added to particle list whenever mouse is clicked
    // ...When is it removed?
    List<Particle> particleList = new List<Particle>();
    // ... Lists cannot be modified while enumerated by a foreach 
    List<Particle> particleListRemove = new List<Particle>();
    
//    bool collision = false; // no collision by default
// ... Collision needs to be handled per particle.

    Rectangle tTextureRectangle = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100);// rectangle placed for 
    //... Rectangle particleRect;  

    //public int particleIndex = 0; **code adding later**
    // ... bad for this example, see above particleListRemove list with this pattern, and below


    MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState();
    MouseState omState;
    // ... having the previous state is much better than a single button 
    

    //PerPixelCollision
    Color[] stiffSpriteData; // ... I get the fixed box, may be better as described in the above objection.

    // ...  tTextureData data is not needed across calls and should be defined locally
    // Color[] tTextureData;      

    // intersect method takes two rectangles and color data to check for collision
    // ... I have stopped here.
 
    //static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA, Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
   // {
 
        // Check every point within the intersection bounds
     //   for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
     //   {
     //       for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
     //       {
     //           // Get the color of both pixels at this point
     //           Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) +
     //                       (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) +
     //                       (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

                // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
     //           if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
     //           {
                    // then an intersection has been found
     //               return true;
     //           }
     //       }
     //   }

        // No intersection found
        return false;
    }

    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        _graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        _graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
        _graphics.ApplyChanges();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        staticSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>("whiteCircle");

        //PerPixelCollision
        stiffSpriteData = new Color[staticSprite.Width * staticSprite.Height];
        staticSprite.GetData<Color>(stiffSpriteData);

        

    }



    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        collision = false;      

        mState = Mouse.GetState();

        clickedMousePos = new Vector2 (mState.Position.X, mState.Position.Y); // updated mouse position when clicked

        //draws a particle ("white circle") with garvity and adds to particleList
        if (mState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && mReleased == true)
        {
            particleList.Add(new Particle(Content.Load<Texture2D>("whiteCircle"), new Vector2(0,1), new Vector2(clickedMousePos.X, clickedMousePos.Y), 1f));

            var listSize = particleList.Count - 1;

            //PerPixelCollision
            tTextureData = new Color[particleList[listSize].texture.Width * particleList[listSize].texture.Height];
            particleList[listSize].texture.GetData<Color>(tTextureData);

            //Rectangle generates for first moving particle in list for now
            particleRect = new Rectangle((int)particleList[listSize].Position.X, (int)particleList[listSize].Position.Y, particleList[0].texture.Width, particleList[0].texture.Height);

            mReleased = false; 
        }

        if (mState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
        {
            mReleased = true;
        }

        foreach (Particle particle in particleList)
        {
            particle.Update(gameTime);
        }

        // Check collision with person
        if (IntersectPixels(tTextureRectangle, tTextureData, particleRect, stiffSpriteData))
        {
            collision = true;
        }
        


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();

        _spriteBatch.Draw(staticSprite, new Vector2(200, 200), null, Color.Black, Rotation, Origin, 0.1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        foreach (Particle particle in particleList)
        {
             particle.Draw(_spriteBatch);     
        }         

        // this is to test wether a collision was actually detected
        if (collision == true)
        {
            _spriteBatch.Draw(staticSprite, new Vector2(500, 500), null, Color.Red, Rotation, Origin, 0.1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }

        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Your Rectangle intersection code never checks to see if there was an actual collision. Replace:

```
        int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);
```

With:

```
        // not colliding check
        if (!rectangleA.Intersects(rectangleB)) return false;

        int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);
'''
```